# What are the chances that an evil God does exist and send us to a hell for the sake of it?

Tags: theology

This question has been on my mind as of late. I’m just curious about the nature of God and its existence.

Take religion out of the picture , Hypothetically, could it be possible that God or the entity that created us, is pure evil, in which he wants his creation to suffer and after our deaths sends us to hell for no apparent reason?

Could this be a possibility?

Let me hear your thoughts.

Have a great day

Comment: This sort of question is discussed in connection with Other Gods objection to Pascal's Wager, which goes back to Diderot. The majority opinion is that such "probabilities" are not well-defined, there are too many options and no reliable way to discriminate among them, see [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/pasc-wag/#H3) and [Evil God challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_God_challenge).

Comment: I have a terrible fear of going to hell +1. I already linked to this on another question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misotheism I wonder if an answer to your question links to Schopenhauer's pessimism at all. gracefully, God would probably be easier to understand if indeed He was evil

Comment: @vqlk. When fearing hell, ask yourself if you’d still believe the claim pertaining to it if hell wasn’t a consequence. If you wouldn’t, then the consequence is irrelevant. I can make up a hell. I can come up to you and say “believe in me or you’re going to hell”. There, just made it up. Now realize that anyone can make it up

Comment: yeah "anything goes" and "it's all up for grabs" @temptrt it's fine mate, not asking for help actually

Comment: From what I see in the world, it seems we are already in hell.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t attach probabilities to these things. All you can ask for is what evidence you see to suggest that there is such a being. Sure, it’s possible, but so are quite literally an infinite number of things. So yes, it is possible that there is an evil god. But it is also possible that there is a god who makes you feel maximal amounts of pleasure for no reason.